# reading from file in batch script

Tags: batch-file

Here is a script I made to find duplicate files into a folder (it is not finished yet).

```
@echo off
dir /b > files.io
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (files.io) do (
    echo %%a
    FOR %%i IN ("%%a") DO (
        echo filename=%%~ni
        dir /b "%%~ni*" | find /v /c ""
        dir /b "%%~ni*" | find /v /c "">countfiles.io
        type countfiles.io
        set /p nbfic=<countfiles.io
        del countfiles.io
        echo %nbfic%
    )
)
```

I have 3 files in the directory, and here is the output :

```
abc.sws
filename=abc
2
2
1
abc.txt
filename=abc
2
2
1
def.txt
filename=def
1
1
1
```

As you can see, both `dir /b "%%~ni*" | find /v /c ""` and `type countfiles.io` return me a valid result, whereas the following does not seem to work :

```
dir /b "%%~ni*" | find /v /c "">countfiles.io
set /p nbfic=<countfiles.io
del countfiles.io
echo %nbfic%
```

But I don't see what could go wrong with this code...
Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: You are inside a code block.  You need to use delayed expansion.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly now!! 
I didn't heard about delayed expansion before but I guess I will have to use it often!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was missing was indeed I was in a code block and I needed to use delayed expansion. I solved my problem adding at the beginning of the file :

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

and replacing `echo %nbfic%` by `echo !nbfic!`

Thanks @Squashman for you help!! :)